Error on verifying token with firebase app check token
im currently having this error, is like when checking token adds an extra '/project' at the beggining, and idk why.

FirebaseAppCheckError: The provided App Check token has incorrect "aud" (audience) claim. Expected "projects/my-project-ba978" but got "my-project-ba978". Make sure the App Check token comes from the same Firebase project as the service account used to authenticate this SDK.

Here is a piece of what im doing:
export async function GET(request) {
  const userToGet = request.nextUrl.searchParams.get("uid");

  const headersList = headers();
  const appCheckToken = headersList.get("X-Firebase-AppCheck");
  const appCheckClaims = await getAppCheck().verifyToken(appCheckToken);
  console.log("appCheckClaims", appCheckClaims);

The token im passing in X-Firebase-AppCheck is the one I get from signInWithPopup function from firebase/auth.
any suggestions?. Thanks in advance
What i did was logging in with signInWithPopup fn and used the retreived token to pass it to the getAppCheck fn and check it, what i want is to match tokens exactly, without the starting '/projects'. I also tried changing the project_id key in the json that google exports for you, adding a /projects initialy, but it ended receiving an 'projects/projects/my-project-ba978'. Still not working
